# *ngIf doesn't delete the element when False, creates new one when True

Tags: html, css, angular, show-hide

I am just starting with Angular and have a problem with `*ngIf`

When the app starts, `*ngIf="item.done"` correctly displays (or not displays) the element based on whether the ToDo `item` is `done`. However, when I click on the element, the `done` state *changes* (I am console.logging it), but the element *doesn't* disappear, whatever the state. Instead, when the state goes back to `done`, it creates the same element again.

[My HTML template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yykOF.png)

[The `onTick()` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrHkM.png) that changes the `item.done` state

1. `item.done = false` **Hidden** [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy8DL.png)
2. 1st click –> `item.done = true` **Shown**
3. 2nd click –> `item.done = false` **Shown**
4. 3rd click –> `item.done = true` **Shown TWICE** [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gq4O.png)

```js
// MOCK DATA

import { Item } from './item';

export const ITEMS: Item[] = [
  {id: 1, title: 'Buy Milk', done: false},
  {id: 2, title: 'Do Math', done: true},
  {id: 3, title: 'Cook food', done: false}
]



// THE COMPONENT TypeScript

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ITEMS } from './mock-items';
import { Item } from './item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Item[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.items = ITEMS
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onTick(item) {
    console.log('Item was: ', item.done)
    item.done = !item.done
    console.log('Item became: ', item.done)

  }

}
```

```html
<!-- THE COMPONENT HTML -->
<div class="list">
  <div class="list--header">
    <h1>List</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="list--content">
    <ul class="list--items">
      <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        <div class="checkbox" (click)="onTick(item)">
          <input type="checkbox" style="display: none">
          <i *ngIf="item.done" class="tick fas fa-check"></i>
        </div>
        {{item.title}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="list--footer">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your code,...

Comment: try `(click)="item.done = !item.done"`

Comment: @Nickolaus added!

Comment: @NadhirFalta tried! Same result.

Comment: Can you put a plunker ?

Comment: plz post your mock code: import { ITEMS } from './mock-items';

Comment: @Nickolaus done!

Comment: @NadhirFalta I don't know how to put Angular 5 there :(

Comment: this is just a guess, inject changeDetetorRef and try running changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() after item.done = !item.done

Comment: I created a plnkr with normal checkboxes and the values seems to be updated fine. I think it has something to do with your css not getting updated check: https://embed.plnkr.co/BiTrEntkwXP2oZf8nH2G/.

Comment: @NadhirFalta Thank you, Nadhir! You inspired me to check if the deal is with the SVG that I was hiding and indeed it was. Posted the workaround but am curious why it doesn't work with SVGs.

Comment: Happy to hear that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

> The problem happens when Font Awesome's SVG, instead of appearing as a child of the `<i *ngIf="item.done" class="tick fas fa-check"></i>`, replaces the element, and so the `*ngIf` attribute disappears. *Looks like we shouldn't ever use Angular attributes on an element with Font Awesome classes **(target the parent element, instead)**.*

**How it Used to Be (Doesn't work)**

```
<i *ngIf="item.done" class="tick fas fa-check"></i>
```

**Solution**

```
<div *ngIf="item.done">
   <i class="tick fas fa-check"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the icon in a DIV... Also it is important to note that ngIf isn't intended to "hide" elements. It will in fact add and remove them from the DOM. If your intent is to hide/show, you should take a look at ngHide.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yess, thank you iHazCode, that's exactly what was needed – wrapping the icon in a DIV.

Thank you for correcting me with hide-show/remove – fixed that!

Comment: Great! I'm glad you got it working, if I can help with anything further don't hesitate to ask.. Would you mind flagging my response as the answer. This will both help future users who encounter this problem, also it will help me raise my "rep" on my new account which I am desperately trying to increase so I can create WIKI entries. :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the list of suggested answers.

You can set the `FontAwesomeConfig` property `autoReplaceSvg` to `nest`, which will automatically nest the SVG inside the `<i>` element instead, and thus not mess up the HTML.

```
<script>
  // Add in your index.html or similar
  FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: 'nest' }
</script>
```

And use it like normal

```
<i class="my-icon fas fa-coffee" data-fa-mask="fas fa-circle"></i>
```

and you'll get the following result

```
<i class="my-icon" data-fa-mask="fas fa-circle" data-fa-processed="">
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-coffee fa-w-16" data-fa-mask="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-fa-processed="" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="coffee" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">...</svg>
</i>
```

Check out the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js) for further reference.